# Rounding off to 6 decimals

Tags: javascript

I would like to round off this code to 6 digits

```
function plus-minus(arr) {

    let pos = 0;
    let neg = 0;
    let zero = 0;
    let len = 6;

    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++){
         if (arr[i] > 0) {
            neg++;
        } else if (arr[i] < 0) {
            pos++;

        } else  {
            zero++;
        } 
           }
    console.log(pos/len);
    console.log(neg/len);
    console.log(zero/len);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Round to at most 2 decimal places (only if necessary)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-only-if-necessary)

Answer (score 1):

For rounding you can use a little trick like this:

```js
var number = 0.00012367
var round = 6;
number = Math.round(number * 10**round) / (10**round)
console.log(number)
```

Or you can use the [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method:

```js
var number = 0.00012367
number = number.toFixed(6)
console.log(number)
```

Comment: You have it with [.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

Comment: That's correct, I forgot about it. I'll add it to answer, thanks

Comment: Thanks, guys I managed to use the .toFixed() method: console.log((pos/len).toFixed(6));
    console.log((neg/len).toFixed(6));
    console.log((zero/len).toFixed(6));